# Import projects option disable in talend integrated suite

Tags: talend

i have to migrate talend from windows to linux.
and when i open talend in linux gui to import projects then i see import option itself disable in talend integrated suite.
can anyone please advice me,why this is happening.

Comment: What do you mean by linux gui ?

Comment: what i intended by linux gui was linux system itself..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely you do not have write permission to the project you are trying to import stuff into.  Write permission needs to be granted in the Talend Administration Center for that project; see the item "Project Authorizations".